# Как сделать чтобы событие клик срабатывало только 1 раз в секунду?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы событие клик срабатывало только 1 раз в секунду? Допустим игрок сделал 3 клика в секунду но сработал только один

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

   alert("1");

}
```

Comment: почитай про debounce/throttle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так например:

```js
document.querySelector('canvas').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   if (new Date().getTime() - this.lastClick < 1000)
      return;
   this.lastClick = new Date().getTime();
   console.log('click');
});
```

```css
canvas {
    border: solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas/>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое))))

Comment: @Ivan912 Пожалуйста, обращайтесь, если такой элемент один, то можно сохранять время в переменную а не лепить в this..